# ¿Cómo obtener palabras en especifico de un JTextArea?

Tags: java, java-swing, java-8

estoy haciendo un minicompilador y necesito extraer todas las palabras reservadas que yo ingrese por medio de un textArea ejemplo de ingreso de datos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

posteriormente, con quiero hacer un barrido del texto ingresado quedándome
únicamente con los if y else este es mi pedazo de código que he hecho:

```
String[] lines; //Gets the text
 lines = get.getText().split("\n");
     for (String line1 : lines) {
            String line = line1;
            if (line.contains("if")) {
                line = line.substring(line.indexOf("if"));
                int theIndex = line.indexOf("if");
                line = line.substring(theIndex);
                System.out.println("info: : "+line);

            } else if (line.contains("else")) {
                line = line.substring(line.indexOf("else"));
                int theIndex = line.indexOf("else");
                line = line.substring(theIndex);
                System.out.println("info2 :" + line);

            }
        }
```

lines es un arreglo en donde guardo la informacion del JtextArea
y el resultado de este codigo me arroga las lineas en donde encuentra un if y un else y yo unicamente necesito el if y else, ejemplo del output:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ejemplo 2 mi entrada en el JtextArea:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Salida con el codigo que realice:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como me gustaria que saliera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿y cual es tu duda/problema?

Comment: el como poder extraer solo los if y else de codigos ingresados por un JtextArea he probado con regex pero no ha funcionado :/ y como puedes ver con el codigo que hice me extrae pero las lineas en donde encuentra un if y/o un else

Comment: La verdad, no está nada claro lo que quieres. ¿Podrías poner un ejemplo de la salida que te gustaría que saliera (puedes darle al botón "editar")?

Comment: acabo de agregar otro ejemplo

Comment: ¿Que ocurriria si tienes una línea con mas de un if o un else?

Comment: se me escapo un if es que el output de ejemplo de como queria que saliera lo hice con una java main class y puse un system.out.println("if") demas

Comment: No sé muy bien cuál es el problema. Si es solo que no imprima el resto de la línea desde el "if", hay una versión de `substring` a la que indicas cuantos caracteres quieres recuperar. Y además, puedes hacer directamente `if (line.contains("if")) {System.out.println("if");}`. Si lo que quieres es distinguir entre `if` del código e `if` de literales, entonces ya estamos hablando de gramáticas y conviene usar herramientas específicas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo primero que se me ocurre es separar palabras sin contar los signos
para ello utilizaré un split, pero se puede utilizar validaciones mas complejas para ello,
pero para este ejemplo sencillo no.

```
String[] elArreglo;

elArreglo = txtElTexto.getText().split("[^a-zA-Z0-9']+");
```

ya solo quedaria validar tus palabras reservadas e imprimirlas

```
for (int i = 0; i < elArreglo.length; i++) {
                    if(elArreglo[i].equals("if") || elArreglo[i].equals("else")){
                        System.out.println(elArreglo[i]);
                }
         }
```

se que es algo sencillo y para un compilador no es suficiente, pero puedes agregar a una lista y manipularlas de mejor manera.

Saludos

Te dejo el código completo:

```
import java.awt.HeadlessException;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class Mini extends JFrame {

    private JTextArea txtElTexto;
    private JScrollPane scCaja;
    private JButton btnElBoton;
    private String[] elArreglo;

    public Mini() throws HeadlessException {
        setSize(500, 500);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setLayout(null);

        txtElTexto = new JTextArea();
        scCaja = new JScrollPane(txtElTexto, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS,
                JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        scCaja.setBounds(50, 10, 380, 350);

        btnElBoton = new JButton("Analiza");
        btnElBoton.setBounds(210, 400, 80, 20);
        btnElBoton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                elArreglo = txtElTexto.getText().split("[^a-zA-Z0-9']+");
                for (int i = 0; i < elArreglo.length; i++) {
                    if (elArreglo[i].equals("if") || elArreglo[i].equals("else")) {
                        System.out.println(elArreglo[i]);
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        add(btnElBoton);
        add(scCaja);

        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Mini mini = new Mini();
    }

}
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias!!